# How to play audio in 'react-native-webrtc'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on an audio call app and was able to integrate the `react-native-webrtc` succesfully using this example https://github.com/jdmg94/react-native-webrtc-example/blob/master/App.js

I am able to stream the video between both devices but unable to stream audio. I am also using `react-native-incall-manager` for playing incoming call/ outgoing call ringtone. But no idea how to play the audio from the remote steam.

Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

imagine receiving remote audio stream, no video, just plain audio stream All you have to do is to make sure your PeerConnection status is `connected` as what you always do with video stream. and react-native-webrtc will play your audio for you. so you dont have to call things like RTCView as you did with video stream.

You can just use PeerConnection and don't set stream's URL to a RTCView